# How to check the root cause of this istio virtualservice invalid resource?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am using istio-1.0.0 and have deployed various resources (e.g: virtualservice, destinationrule, gateways, etc). Upon checking grafana `Istio Galley Dashboard`, i found there is a `failed` metrics indicated in the picture below. It seems there is a invalid `virtualservice` resource. How to check which one is it? Is there any script or tools that can help me to check it?

[image: Error Image]

Comment: can you provide your virtualservices configuration? Also are you able access your pod and do smth insight it? Maybe this issue not relates to virtualservice, but to pod accessibility

Comment: That’s the thing. We have so many virtual services configuration, decentralized on each app repo. Should inget all of it and put is as yaml file?